# Finding out how many days I have left

Tags: swift

I have two variables

```
nextShoppingDay = 2

Today = 5
```

I have an array for days of the week 
going from 0 to 6:

```
0 Monday
1 Tuesday
2 Wednesday
3 Thursday 
4 Friday
5 Saturday
6 Sunday
```

I need to write a small function that finds out how many days are left for example today is `5(Saturday)` and next shopping is on `2(Wednesday)`
so I guess I need a mathematical formula?

So far I have tried subtracting one number from another but it bore no fruit 
what I need is the number of the remaining days;

```
 remainingDays = nextShoppingDay - today
```

**How can I modify this to get the remaining days remaining until the next shopping day?**

Comment: You have 1,202,202,224,966,844 days left, enjoy your life!

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify how many days you need as a result. Is the requirement to be inclusive of today and/or the next shopping day? i.e. do you expect 3, 4, or 5? (my assumption is it moves forward and not something negative like 3 days ago (-3)  Be precise in your requirements, assume nothing, make questions such that there is no ambiguity to them.

Comment: How would you do it yourself? This is kind of what development is all about-solving problems. Work on it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
remainingDays = (nextShoppingDay + 7 - today) % 7
```

But I advise you to write your questions clearer.

Comment: Serega, this worked perfectly, but can you explain to me the last %7 bit?

Comment: @DamoTamo just calculating of division remainder. Since we add 7 to nextShoppingDay - today, we can't get a number less than 0 but we can get a number greater than 6. We should therefore "normalize" it, i.e. throw away the part that is the whole week - seven days.

Of course, all that is right only if  your dates don't differ by more than a week. Otherwise you shouldn't convert dates to week days.